# how to use nginx 3rd party module when proxying connections to application servers

Tags: node.js, tomcat, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I developed a **Nginx 3rd party dynamic module** and did required configuration in *nginx.conf*. Able to run that module and see it doing processing. This module reads request request header, cookies etc., does some business logic execution and modify response header then send back response to client.

**Problem** -: "How to use nginx module when proxying connections to application servers"
I'm be using Nginx as proxy server and Tomcat or Node as application server and my application hosted on app server. I'm able to route the request through both web & app server and get response back but module isn't getting invoked. Not sure how to link/configure it so that my able to intercept request and modify response header as per need.

**Flow** -: Browser <-> Web Server (module sits here) <-> Application Server

Has anybody explored this part? If yes then please help.

Comment: Are you trying to write your own reverse-proxying module, or are you trying to use nginx's reverse-proxy module chained-together with your own module? What does your module actually do?

Comment: Module will read every request header cookie and based on some business logic will allow or block or through captcha on request. This module have been developed but struggling with how to invoke for the app deployed on app sever.

Comment: I'm not Nginx expert, but you probably should be able to write your module so that it *either* performs a redirect (or does whatever you want to do for CAPTCHA) *or* allows Nginx to handle the request as usual (e.g. by proxying). You shouldn't have to write your own proxying code yourself.